# What does keras.backend.clip do?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am trying to create a custom loss function and when looking at other examples of loss functions online, I found this example:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # normalize y_pred
    y_pred /= keras.backend.sum(y_pred, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    # clip to prevent NaN's and Inf's
    y_pred = keras.backend.clip(y_pred, keras.backend.epsilon(), 1 - keras.backend.epsilon())
    # calc
    loss = ...
    return loss
```

I do not know what "keras.backend.clip" does and any documentation I find on Google ([here](http://tensorflow.biotecan.com/python/Python_1.8/tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clip.html) and [here](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/TensorFlow.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clip.html)) define clip as a function that does elementwise clipping. I dont know what clip means so "elementwise clipping" means nothing in particular. I assume that it must replace values over a threshold or something like that. Is there a more mathematical definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clip, to me, means to set a value to a threshold if it exceeds the threshold. For example, if we clip data at 5, then 0 is 0, 1 is 1, but 6 is 5, and so is anything higher. The word comes from thinking about clipping grass off at a given height. Of course, one can also clip above a threshold - or both.